# EF Code First 6.1 Change PK Key from int to long

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

This is similar to [EF Code First 6.1 Change ID from Int to Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421081/ef-code-first-6-1-change-id-from-int-to-long) but a bit more specific as I have code generated by EF but it doesn't work with my local db.

`Add-Migration` generated the following migration:

```cs
namespace NuGetGallery.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    
    public partial class UpdateKeyToLong : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.PackageStatistics");
            AlterColumn("dbo.PackageStatistics", "Key", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.PackageStatistics", "Key");
        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.PackageStatistics");
            AlterColumn("dbo.PackageStatistics", "Key", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.PackageStatistics", "Key");
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to update my database by doing: `Update-Database -Verbose -ConfigurationTypeName MigrationsConfiguration`

I get the following output:

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose -ConfigurationTypeName MigrationsConfiguration
Using StartUp project 'NuGetGallery'.
Using NuGet project 'NuGetGallery'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'NuGetGallery' (DataSource: (localdb)\mssqllocaldb, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
Applying explicit migrations: [202009252154324_UpdateKeyToLong].
Applying explicit migration: 202009252154324_UpdateKeyToLong.
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PackageStatistics] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.PackageStatistics]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 'PK_dbo.PackageStatistics' is not a constraint.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
ClientConnectionId:6fa4ac08-e7d6-489f-b807-e53603b560ec
Error Number:3728,State:1,Class:16
'PK_dbo.PackageStatistics' is not a constraint.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

Was the auto-generated code by EF wrong? Is there something I should include here?

UPDATE 1:

here's what the Designer shows from VS (before the migration):

[image]

UPDATE 2:

[image]

double clicking in VS gives me:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PackageStatistics]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_PackageStatistics] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Key] ASC);
```

Comment: What's the actual name of the primary key constraint on `dbo.PackageStatistics`? It looks like it doesn't match what EF is expecting it to be.

Comment: Added an update that shows the Designer view from VS before the migration

Comment: There it is: It's called `PK_PackageStatistics`, not `PK_dbo.PackageStatistics`. Either the primary key was not created by Migrations or someone renamed it after it was created.

Comment: ah progress! `The constraint 'PK_PackageStatistics' is being referenced by table 'GallerySettings', foreign key constraint 'FK_GallerySettings_PackageStatistics_DownloadStatsLastAggregatedId'.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.` I guess at this point, I need to Drop & Add the FKs until it works like the other question?

Comment: Try this: `EXEC sp_rename N'[dbo].[PK_PackageStatistics]', N'PK_dbo.PackageStatistics', 'OBJECT';`

Comment: noob question, would I do that as a part of the migration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222095/discussion-between-tyler-james-leonhardt-and-madreflection).